# How to remove an element from a fixed array USING ONLY for loops and additional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Without using arraylists, arraycopy, or any other imported method, but simply just using for loops and an additional array, how does one remove the **first occurrence** of a certain element?

this is my code so far:

```
public class remover {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     //initial array
    int[] oldArray = {1,2,3,4};

    //value to remove is 3


    //define the new array with smaller size
    int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.length];

    //cycle through array
    for(int i=0;i < oldArray.length;i++) 
    {
        if(oldArray[i] == 3) {
            for(int k=0; k<i; k++) {
                newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
            }
            for(int m=i; m<oldArray.length; m++) {
                newArray[m] = oldArray[m];
            }


        }

    }


for(int i=0; i<oldArray.length; i++) {
System.out.println(oldArray[i]);
}
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried..??

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you trying to copy the old array to a new one without the target element or are you trying to modify the old array in-place? What if there are multiple matches for the element to remove? Remove them all or just the first?

Comment: Why do you have such odd, arbitrary requirements?

Comment: @Phil I think that question could be asked about most questions on SO.

Comment: @Adam too true, but why do you?

Comment: @ggorlen Exactly! Trying to copy the old array into a new one without the target element. Then I'll just assign the old array reference to the new one. Just the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through twice like this

```
    int[] oldArray = {1,2,3,3,4};

    int valToremove = 3;
    int numToRemove = 0;

    for (int x : oldArray) {
        if (x == valToremove)
            numToRemove++;
    }

    //define the new array with smaller size
    int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.length - numToRemove];

    //cycle through array
    int i = 0;
    for (int x : oldArray) {
        if (x != valToremove) {
            newArray[i] = x;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I'm only trying to do it for the first occurrence. Wouldn't this delete all occurrences from the array?

Comment: @Adam I was showing how to be flexible with your code.  If you only have one element then this code would still work.  If you want to change your requirements to only remove the **first** matching number then this can be easily achieved by adding a boolean variable `alreadyRemoved = false` which can be set to true when removed and the `if` becoming `if (x != valToremove || !alreadyRemoved) `

Comment: I tried your code, and got arrayoutofbounds with numtoremove at 0. when I changed it to 1, it changed every element in the array to 0

Comment: Yes, you should change `int valToremove = 3;`